# Passing user_id via params and then checking user_id in controller doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a remove_attendee action in my events controller. I pass it a :user_id of the user to remove and :id of the event to remove the user from.

Basically, I want to double check that the user being requested to be removed is the current_user. You should only be able to remove yourself from an event. My route is setup as so:

```
post "/remove_attendee/:user_id" => "events#remove_attendee", :as=>:remove_attendee
```

then I pass current_user.id as :user_id as such:

```
<%= button_to 'Decline Event', remove_attendee_event_path(:user_id => @current_user.id), 
                                                              :method => :post,
                                                              :class => "button" %>
```

However, when I double check if :user_id == current_user.id in my events controller, it doesn't work:

```
def remove_attendee
    session[:return_to] = request.referrer
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    if params[:user_id] == current_user.id
      if @event.remove_attendance(params[:user_id])
        flash[:success] = "User removed from event."
      else
        flash[:error] = "Could not remove user"
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = "Could not remove user"
    end
    redirect_to session[:return_to]
  end
```

I eventually want the event owner (@event.owner_id) to be able to remove attendees as well...but this is the part that is breaking. It should work...i'm checking the value I just passed. I put some debug info in:

```
def remove_attendee
    session[:return_to] = request.referrer
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    flash[:pass] = false
    flash[:test1] = params[:user_id]
    flash[:test2] = current_user.id
    if params[:user_id] == current_user.id
      flash[:pass] = true
      if @event.remove_attendance(params[:user_id])
        flash[:success] = "User removed from event."
      else
        flash[:error] = "Could not remove user"
      end
    end
    redirect_to session[:return_to]
  end
```

when the page reloads after running remove_attendee, :pass = false, :test1 = 1, :test2 = 1.

how is it possible that this isn't passing?

Comment: Can you add some debug and see what `param[:user_id]` and `current_user.id` is at that moment?

Comment: Just tested it...params[:user_id] and current_user.id are both equal to 1...so it should pass...but doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out. params[:user_id] is a string, so it doesn't equate to current_user.id which is an integer. So I did this:

```
params[:user_id].to_i == current_user.id
```

this worked!

Comment: Nice, I should have spotted that one. You can accept your own answers but you might have to wait awhile.